# asp.net file path display in textbox with browse button like fileupload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, textbox

Ok, here's what I want.  I have a FormView with several fields, one of which is a filepath.  I want to display that filepath in a textbox, then provide a browse button so users can update it (similiar to using a FileUpload control).  I just need a way for the user to browse their filesystem and return the path, not to actually upload the file.

FileUpload control does display the path afterwards (at least in IE), but there doesn't seem to be a way to bind the initial value of the textbox to the original path.

I tried setting the value by doing a `(FileUpload1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text =` in the page load event, but I can't get this to work.  Can't access the FileUpload1 control there.

Any guidance on how I can do this?  FileUpload provides 70% of the functionality, but can't seem to get the rest of the way.

EDIT: To further explain, here is the sequence of events I need:
1. When the form loads, bind the textbox to the original file path.
2. When someone clicks on the browse button and selects another file path, replace the value in the textbox.
3. I need to be able to grab that path out of the textbox (or FileUpload control) to update the database record.

I've seen explanations of steps 2 and 3, but nothing for step 1.  Also, I don't want to have 2 textboxes visible, as thats ugly and confusing to the user.

Comment: you do not need FindControl at all in my opinion all you need to do is on the button click of the upload control check for something like the following `if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile){ }` then to get the name of the file that was selected it would be `this.FIleUpload1.FileName` you can assign a FilePath and display it in a label or TextBox as well somthing like `var fileName= fileName + FilePath + this.FileUpload1.FileName` for example.. this is actually not very difficult and there are tons of working examples on `SO` as well as the internet

Comment: @DJKRAZE -Doesn't look like you quite understood my question... I need to know how to display the original path before its changed by the browse button.  FindControl is needed because I stated this is inside of a FormView.  If there are so many examples, link to one of them and make that your answer for eassy points.

Comment: perhaps you may want to update the question its current state has confused me.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as

```
 TextBox1.Text = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

To set the file path in the textbox

But if the control is nested your going to have to find its parent first before you can use it. The example below is if its in a FormView labeled FormView_1.

```
 FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)FormView_1.FindControl("FileUpload1");
```

If FileUpload1 is not null then you can call the code above

Comment: why not just use the internal function `.HasFile` ?? I've never had issues with getting file names or paths using the FileUpload.HasFile method check

Comment: @DJ KRAZE .HasFile is good to check if a file is even been selected by the FileUpload, but it sounded like the trouble was coming from pasting the selected path in a textbox. Maybe I miss read it though

Comment: @MAW74656 I updated the find control to look in a FormView. And the answer to your question is: FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName is how you find the file path before you change it.

Comment: @Luk6e -This is good, but still doesn't explain how to set the textbox to show the current path initially.